# Bash, ffmpeg and pipe musings

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, pipe

I am trying to run Monit with this script. This script is running perfectly under root from command line however, when I try to run it from shell environment, it does not work after pipe sign, i.e. when I debug I can see it runs till pipe sign and ffmpeg command after pipe sign is not running neither from root nor any other user. Your help would be appreciated.

```html
#!/bin/sh
pid_file="/home/tester/radio1.pid"
name="radio1"

case "$1" in
 start)

    echo "Start radio";
    rtl_fm -f 93.2970M -M wbfm | /opt/ffmpeg_qsv/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -f s16le -ac 1 -i pipe:0  -acodec libmp3lame -ab 128k -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/live/test" &
        ch_pid=$!
    echo $ch_pid
    echo $ch_pid > $pid_file
    echo `( >>/dev/null )&`;
         ;;

 stop)
    echo "Stop radio";
    PID=`cat $pid_file 2>/dev/null`
    kill $PID >/dev/null 2>&1
        rm -f $pid_file
         ;;
        *)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/$name {start|stop}"
         exit 1
         ;;
 esac


exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a double quote missing somewhere. In line 9 you have a hanging quote. Check out http://www.shellcheck.net/ which is awesome for small errors like this.

Comment: Actually, original code did not had hanging quote in line 9. So even without hanging code, it is not working. I am guessing the problem lies in piping itself but I can't truly pinpoint why piping might be not working, so I need some help.